# Why wont my 1000kv brushless motor work with a 10x4.5 propeller?

Tags: brushless-motors, lipo-batteries, propellers, batteries, diy

When I run my A2212/13T 1000Kv brushless motor by itself with 11.1 or 7.4 volts(i am using 2 lipo 3.7volts 900mah and a li-ion 3.7v 900mah in series that I connected with alligator clips) it runs fine. But when I add the propeller(10x4.5) it came with, it will run for a second then stop and make a series of beeps, which looks like it's trying to reboot itself. I am using a 30A ESC. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You say this is a 10x4.5x2 propeller? Or is it a tri-blade?

Comment: no, it is just a normal blade 10x4.5, search up 10x4.5 propeller and the picture of what I'm talking about should come up.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're most likely running into current limits with your battery setup. The motor you linked to is [spec'd](https://www.rhydolabz.com/documents/26/BLDC_A2212_13T.pdf) for even more aggressive propellers (*e.g. 10x5 and 10x6*), so it's likely not the problem.

It's hard to say for sure without knowing more about the specific battery cells you're using to construct your "franken-pack" (*I suspect this is a follow-up to [your question](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/can-i-put-lipo-and-li-ion-batteries-in-series) about series-connected battery cells*), but it's likely that your 900 mAh cells aren't rated for the continuous discharge required to spin a larger 10x4.5 propeller.

The failure mode you describe sounds like this is happening:

1. Initial propeller rotation from rest is supported by the burst discharge capabilities of the battery cells

   - This comes at the cost of abnormally high battery terminal voltage sag
2. The ESC freaks out because the battery voltage it sees has dramatically decreased and isn't recovering

   - ESC responds by cutting power to the motor and sounding a fault code

Comment: what you have answered sounds about right, but to solve this problem what battery do you suggest I should buy

Comment: You should look into higher discharge rate 3S LiPo battery packs, e.g. 30C or higher.